# Finding vector coordinates in a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

We have two bases: $B =$ {$ (2,6,-1), (3,3,1), (1,0,1)$} and $C =$ {$ (2,0,0), (1,1,2), (1,-1,-8)$}. I'm trying to find the coordinates of a vector $x$ in the basis $C$, if $x_B = (2,1,-3)$ .

What steps should I do in order to calculate the coordinates? Thanks!

Comment: Calculate the transition matrix $T^{B}_{C}$.

Comment: @skullph Thanks! I have perhaps a silly question. Is transition matrix from B to C the same as transition matrix from C to B?

Comment: No quite, the transition matrix from $B$ to $C$ gets you the coordinates of your basis vectors from $B$ in the basis $C$ whereas the transition matrix from $C$ to $B$ gets you the coordinates of your basis vectors from $C$ in the basis $B$. If you have $T^{C}_{B}$ however, you can get $T^{B}_{C}$ by  $T^{B}_{C} =  (T^{C}_{B})^{-1}$.

Comment: @skullph So I need to do transition matrix from B to C in order to find the coordinates?

Comment: Yes that should work

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ such that $ \alpha(2,0,0)+\beta(1,1,2)+\gamma(1,-1,8)=2(2,6,-1)+(3,3,1)-3(1,0,1)$

i.e. $\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 2 & 8 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \alpha \\ \beta \\ \gamma \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 3 & 1 \\ 6 & 3 & 0 \\ -1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \\ -3 \end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{pmatrix} \alpha \\ \beta \\ \gamma \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 2 & 8 \end{pmatrix} ^{-1}\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 3 & 1 \\ 6 & 3 & 0 \\ -1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \\ -3 \end{pmatrix}$